# IntelliJ IDEA - stop wrapping lines in class fields declaration

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting

Having set the hard wrap limit to 100 columns, many long types declared as class fields are wrapped on their assignment.

```
private static final MyLongLongLongType myLongLongLongType = new MyLongLongLongType();
```

becomes

```
private static final MyLongLongLongType myLongLongLongType =
     new MyLongLongLongType();
```

Is it possible to disable wrapping only for class fields declaration and assignment in IntelliJ IDEA `2018.2`? I'd like to maintain the hard wrap for all the other code.

Comment: +1 for this. I don't think that's possible so far. It would be good to have a special "annotation" or comment (as `// region` is) for doing this.

Comment: @lealceldeiro there are formatter:off and formatter:on comments that you can place in your code, but I don't really like them